# How to change UISearchController.searchBar.height in iOS11?

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationbar, uisearchcontroller

navigationBar.frame.size.height is 44.0f;

but UISearchController.searchBar.height is 56.0f;

`[self.view addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];`

How to change UISearchController.searchBar.height in iOS11 ?
searchBar.frame.size.height = 35 is of no use

[image]